# Wrote a function to hide a widget but can't make it work without an event listener. I need it to run when page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I installed a Cross-sell and upsell app that shows product recommendations at the button of the product page. I'm creating a brand new product landing page template where I would not like to display this widget. There's no setting to hide it on specific product templates and the app code is nowhere to be found on my theme so I guess it's running on the app's backend.

Anyways, with useful Chrome developer tools I see the rendered div's ID so I wrote the following function for it:

```js
const hide = () => {
  let x = document.getElementById("ac-recommendation-block").style.display = "none";
  console.log('Its working');
  
  // ac-recomendation-block is the div's ID.
```

Now, I need it to run when the page is fully loaded, preferably asynchronously (the widget is asynch so it takes some time to load). I tried using `window.onload` and I tried setting timeout without any luck. The script does work because if I add a button that runs the function, it does hide the widget, but I want it to run automatically so it will hide it right after it loads (user won't see it since it loads at the very bottom of the page).

Comment: Why don't you just add this to your page? `<style>#ac-recommendation-block { display: none; }</style>`

Comment: after defining a function you need to call one for it to work (if it's not IIIFE), so beneath call hide();

Comment: You also need to close out your function with `}`.

Comment: @blex LOL and here I was overcomplicating stuff with js. Guess I was having tunnel vision on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Raphael I did try it with no luck, but as Blex suggested, it was way easier with css.